# How use a result from a function as data to another?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have created a way to get the toss for a cricket match. I need to use the result from `toss()` to use as conditon in an if statement in another fucntion result()

```
import random
tos = input("Choose head or tail \n")
def toss():
     if tos == "head":
          result = ["Bat", "Bowl"]
          r =print(random.choice(result))
     elif tos == "tail":
            result = ["Bat", "Bowl"]
            r =print(random.choice(result))
     else:
           print("ERROR!")
toss()
def result():
    # i need the value in toss either bat or bowl to be used in if
     if r =="Bat":
        runs = ["1" , "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","W",]
        runs_2=print(random.choice(runs))

result()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must `return` the result from toss then assign that to a variable that you pass as an argument to `result`

```
import random
tos = input("Choose head or tail \n")
def toss():
  if tos == "head":
      result = ["Bat", "Bowl"]
      r =print(random.choice(result))
  return r
 elif tos == "tail":
        result = ["Bat", "Bowl"]
        r =print(random.choice(result))
    return r
 else:
       print("ERROR!")

myToss = toss()#instantiation of return from function

def result(r)
    if r =="Bat":
        runs = ["1" , "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","W",]
        runs_2=print(random.choice(runs))

result(myToss) #added parameter
```

Comment: Thanks

But i need to display the runs if the toss is bat but here it doesnt

Comment: That's because `myToss` is `None`, it simply cannot be anything else. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

So first, your function should take a parameter for `tos`. Using global variables can lead to troubles and should be avoided **whenever possible**.

Also, you're setting the `r` variable in the `toss()` function. This means `r` only exists in `toss()`'s scope, and will be unavailable outside of it.

Second, even if `r` was a global variable set in `toss()`, since `print` doesn't return anything, `r` will always be `None`. You must remove the `print`.

Third, don't use a global variable to get a function's output (well unless you **really** need to). Instead, you should `return` something.

```
def toss(tos):
    result = ["Bat", "Bowl"]
    if tos == "head":
        r = random.choice(result)
    elif tos == "tail":
        r = random.choice(result)
    else:
        raise ValueError("You must choose 'head' or 'tail'")
    print(r)
    return r

def result(this_is_NOT_r):
    if this_is_NOT_r =="Bat":
        runs = ["1" , "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","W",]
        return random.choice(runs)

print(result(toss(input("Choose head or tail \n"))))
```